# python pandas dataframe adding total column with filtered criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file where I compare different pieces of information for different views of an underlying dataset.  The goal is to list out the pieces of information and compare the totals.

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"Measures": 
['Country','State','County','City'], 
"Green": ['Included','Excluded','Included','Included'], "Orange": 
['Excluded', 'Excluded', 'Excluded', 'Included']})
```

I have the following underlying dataset:

```
Location    Green    Orange
Country     1        6
State       3        10
County      2        15
City        5        20
```

I would like the final outcome to look like this:

```
Measures    Green    Orange
Country     Included Excluded
State       Excluded Excluded
County      Included Excluded
City        Included Included
Total       8        20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df` to mask the underlying dataframe's values before computing the sum.

```
m = df.eq('Included')   
# Assume df2 is your underlying DataFrame.
v = df2[m].sum()
# Assign the total back as a new row in df.    
df.loc['Total', :] = v[df2.dtypes != object]

df
      Measures     Green    Orange
0      Country  Included  Excluded
1        State  Excluded  Excluded
2       County  Included  Excluded
3         City  Included  Included
Total      NaN         8        20
```

---

Another option, if you want a more identical output is to set "Measures" and "Locations" as the indexes respectively.

```
df = df.set_index('Measures')
df2 = df2.set_index('Location')

m = df.eq('Included') 
v = df2[m].sum()
df.loc['Total', :] = v

df
             Green    Orange
Measures                    
Country   Included  Excluded
State     Excluded  Excluded
County    Included  Excluded
City      Included  Included
Total            8        20
```

Comment: coldspeed, thank you very much!  Both answers are extremely helpful!